# AJAX.BEGINFORM OnSuccess not firing if using enctype = "multipart/form-data"

Tags: model-view-controller, enctype

I trust you are well, at the moment I am having a problem trying to get OnSuccess (or any other post operation) to complete if I use the following code:

(View)

```
using(Ajax.BeginForm("ManualEntryCreate", null, new AjaxOptions
{
  HttpMethod = "Post",
  OnSuccess = "alert('test');"}, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
{
  etc
```

Everything works fine as it should, the files selected are passed to the method in the controller (I'm not actually uploading files, merely passing the filenames of the selection into a database)

However, upon return OnSuccess (or anything e.g. OnComplete) is not firing.

If I remove

```
new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"}
```

OnSuccess works but I need to pass the variable that contains the selected files into the method so I need the enctype component added. I've checked the Network/Console logs and a JSON response is being sent back no problem. It is just that any On'X' post completion events are not firing.

Is this simply a limitation with Ajax.BeginForm or am I missing something fundamental here? Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad - I had intercepted the request (legacy code) using a Windows.EventListener that prevented default behaviour from occurring. It only activated if I was trying to submit a multipart form.